# Flyway not picking up my sql file for migration

Tags: java, flyway

I am using flyway version 4.1.2

I have a schema called SAPDATA. I am looking to execute the below script V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql . I see that my sql file has been ignored by flyway, it has filtered out my resource.

I already have tables in the schema, so I set baselineOnMigrate to true in order to migrate my script.

**Please can you let me know whether I should explicitly set the schema name?
I am not sure why my sql file is getting filtered out?**

Please can you advise if I am missing any specific settingson my flyway so that my sql gets executed?

**Execution code**

```
      @Override
        protected void doOperation(DatabaseConfig.DataSourceConfig databaseConfig, String location) {
            final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
            flyway.setLocations(location);
            flyway.setDataSource(databaseConfig.getUrl(), databaseConfig.getUsername(), databaseConfig.getPassword());
           flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
           flyway.migrate();
        }

**Execution logs**
 17:51:46.073 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector - Spring Jdbc available: false
17:51:46.074 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.SqlScriptFlywayCallback - Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
17:51:46.074 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration/sap' (Prefix: '', Suffix: '.sql')
17:51:46.074 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Determining location urls for classpath:db/migration/sap using ClassLoader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@446cdf90 ...
17:51:46.074 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning URL: file:/C:/dev/workspaces/intellij-workspaces/reference-data-system/database/target/classes/db/migration/sap
17:51:46.075 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
17:51:46.077 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.FileSystemClassPathLocationScanner - Scanning starting at classpath root in filesystem: C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-workspaces\reference-data-system\database\target\classes\
17:51:46.077 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.FileSystemClassPathLocationScanner - Scanning for resources in path: C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-workspaces\reference-data-system\database\target\classes\db\migration\sap (db/migration/sap)
17:51:46.098 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Found resource: db/migration/sap/V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql
17:51:46.706 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Validating migrations ...
17:51:46.757 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration/sap' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
17:51:46.757 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning URL: file:/C:/dev/workspaces/intellij-workspaces/reference-data-system/database/target/classes/db/migration/sap
17:51:46.757 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
17:51:46.774 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Found resource: db/migration/sap/V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql
17:51:46.777 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration/sap' (Prefix: 'R', Suffix: '.sql')
17:51:46.777 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning URL: file:/C:/dev/workspaces/intellij-workspaces/reference-data-system/database/target/classes/db/migration/sap
17:51:46.778 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
17:51:46.789 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Filtering out resource: db/migration/sap/V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql (filename: V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql)
17:51:46.791 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classes at 'classpath:db/migration/sap' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
17:51:46.791 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning URL: file:/C:/dev/workspaces/intellij-workspaces/reference-data-system/database/target/classes/db/migration/sap
17:51:46.791 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
17:51:46.803 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Filtering out resource: db/migration/sap/V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql (filename: V0.0.1_1__baseline.sql)
17:51:47.107 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.398s)
17:51:47.240 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.sqlserver.SQLServerDbSupport - SQLServer does not support setting the schema for the current session. Default schema NOT changed to SAPDATA
17:51:47.330 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbSchemas - Schema [SAPDATA] already exists. Skipping schema creation.
17:51:48.343 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table - Locking table [SAPDATA].[schema_version]...
17:51:48.394 [main] DEBUG org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table - Lock acquired for table [SAPDATA].[schema_version]
17:51:48.793 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema [SAPDATA]: 1
17:51:48.877 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema [SAPDATA] is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Comment: I don't get it. Have you already tried setting the schema using Flyway#setSchemas(String... schemas)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that option as well. For some reason its filtering out my sql file.

Comment: So the log you posted is generated if you use #setSchema(..)? Because in the code you don't.

Comment: I have updated the above with the most recent logs that I got for the code that I ran above. This is without setting the schema name. Please can you advise what I might be missing?

Comment: The baseline is set to 1, however the script has version 0. I would assume that this is the reason script is not applied.

Comment: Thanks @hofi , that was the issue. I had to upgrade the version number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your logs, you already have a schema with version 1, though your script is with version 0.

If you want your script to be applied you have to increase it's version, because all the scripts with lower versions than current are skipped.